# How to use joins in code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm actually not too sure if I even need a join. It's really the only thing while learning SQL that I didn't really understand or pay attention too, but basically I have 2 tables:

```
games
subgames
```

In games I have gamesname row:

```
Final Fantasy
Metal Gear Solid
Yu-Gi-Oh
```

In subgames I have subgamesname row:

```
Metal Gear Rising
```

They both have autoincrement for an id. However I am trying to display my games as clickable links then refreshes the page and shows the subgames. So for example if I clicked `Metal Gear Solid` it would take you to `games.php?subgame=Metal%20Gear%20Solid` and show `Metal Gear Rising`. Here is what I have so far, but it does not show `Metal Gear Rising`, probably because I have the games in one table and sub games in another with no reference to each other.

So my question is, how can I reference them in my code to display properly?

```
<?php
$sub = $_GET['subgame'];
if($sub){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $sub FROM games");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
printf("%s<br />", $row["subgamename"], $row["subgamename"]);
 }
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT gamename FROM games ORDER BY gamename");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
printf("<a href='games.php?subgame=%s'> %s </a><br />", $row["gamename"], $row["gamename"]);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Joins are used when there's a relationship between two tables. How are games and subgames related to each other? Is there a `game_id` column in the `subgames` table that says what it's a subgame of?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a relationship between the two tables. The subgames table should contain a foreign key of the ID of the parent game table to link the two together.

Comment: Here you can see a good visual explanation of joins:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Yea I really should have paid attention to the joins, but I really couldn't make sense of them. As far as I know neither are linked. I have games table and subgames table. They both have an autoincrement key, but not tied to either table. They just add an id as soon as I add another entry. I really want to learn it, it's just complicated for me. I'm wondering if it would just be easier to just have a games table and then have subgames somehow listed under the games table. I guess I would have to label each subgame under the game, but that would require me listing the same game over and over.

Comment: If there's nothing linking the two tables, then how is anyone supposed to know which subgames are related to which games. You need to design your schema to match the needs. Relational databases don't have the notion of "subgames somehow listed under the games table". You relate data in tables by using foreign keys.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but if you couldn't make sense of joins and don't understand the answers we're giving you, you're out of your league and need to find a new job.,

Comment: I got everything else down, the design, the php, and the database layout with the information, it's just the inner join I don't quite catch. It's the day in class that put me to sleep, so excuse me for wanting to learn on something that I regret sleeping through. However the reason I am left in the dark, is I am not understanding the foreign key aspect. Is it basically like I am using just one table? So instead of typing the same game over and over I would be typing the foreign key over and over? I guess this is where a control panel would need to be coded?

Answer (score 1):

Your query it's wrong. What is:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT $sub FROM games");` ????

**it should be**

```
mysql_query("SELECT subgamesname FROM subgamesname where gamesName ='".$_GET['subgame']."'");
```

But your name of parameter it's not intuitive `subgame`, it's should be `gameName` because you search through games name

Comment: See with this code, it would search for the game name inside of subgamesname, but I don't have games listed in both tables, didn't see the point in listing both twice.

Answer (score 0):

The query you probably want is:

```
$sub = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub']);
$query = "
    SELECT subgamesname
    FROM subgames s
    JOIN games g ON g.id = s.game_id
    WHERE g.gamesname = '$sub'
";
```

I'm assuming the `subgames` table has a `game_id` column that's a foreign key to the `games` table. You need to replace those column names with what you're actually using in your schema.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, it just doesn't make sense to me? How does it know to list all the sub games from the game that is in the games table? I know it gets the game name from $sub, but neither the gameid or the subgame id is linked together or in order. It also doesn't work for me, it gives Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /public_html/series.php on line 54.

Comment: It knows because they're linked by the `g.id = s.game_id` relationship. Did you replace those with the actual column names from your tables?